# What's inside a giant gut?

Tags: bellyfat

When a person gets fatter, their gut becomes round and bloated. For example, this man:

http://cfs7.blog.daum.net/image/22/blog/2007/10/16/14/58/471453134fcb8&filename=giant_gut.jpg

What's inside of the belly? A layer of fat just beneath the skin can't be entirely responsible for all of it. Is it all undigested food? large intestine? small intestine? Are his organs bigger?

Comment: Try Googling "fat person autopsy" images... but not while you're eating.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jda2F.jpg

Have you seen this picture? I think it helps to answer your question.

I tried looking for a good one similar to this but side view but could not find such a picture.

Gauging from that picture it seems the layer of fat is quite a significant portion of the lateral size and I believe if there were a side view it would be even more significant. However it also appears that the internal organs are also a bit larger.